# WPF Navigation to a new Page displays only half the Page

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation

Currently, I'm trying to display another page within the same window on the window load. The program navigates to the new page fine but the data on the page is cut off(Sort of like a half-loaded picture).

My Main window's code is simply:

```xml
<DockPanel>
   <Frame x:Name="_mainFrame" />
</DockPanel>
```

and

```cs
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        }

        private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _mainFrame.Content = new MainPage();
        }
```

The Code for the second page is only the xaml:

```xml
<Grid Background="AliceBlue">
        <TextBlock Text="Welcome To The Store!" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="DarkBlue" FontSize="40" FontFamily="Algerian" Margin="0,0,0,340"/>
        <Button x:Name="ExistingCustomer" Content="Existing Customer" Height="25" Width="105" Margin="348,160,347,265"/>
        <Button x:Name="NewCustomer" Content="New Customer" Margin="348,210,347,215" Height="25" Width="105"/>
        <Button x:Name="Guest" Content="Guest" Margin="348,265,347,160" Height="25" Width="105"/>
    </Grid>
```

The Page stops halfway through the textblock and doesn't display any of the buttons.

I've tried to change the `MainWindow_Loaded` code to `_MainFrame.Navigate(new MainPage());` and `this.content = new MainPage();` but the problem still occurs.

### Edit

Added the screenshots:

[The Page should Display this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrNlK.jpg)

[Instead, it Displays this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z95Ew.jpg)

Comment: can you please provide some screen cuts to understand the issue

Comment: remove height and width properties from your window element

Comment: @MathanKumar Oh, that fixed it. Thanks!